# Why are my SEOmatic Entry Metas not overriding Sitewide SEO?

Tags: seo

SEOmatic is working as normal locally, but since I put the site up on production the Meta Entry fieldtype isn't overwriting the Site Metas.

I have my

```
{% hook 'seomaticRender' %}
```

set up in my head as normal. I've created my Meta fieldset and added it to each entry type. I've set up SEOmatic before and never seen this issue, so I assume I missed something while bringing the site onto the hosting.

Answer (score 2):

If you added the SEO Meta FieldType to existing entries, you'll need to re-save each section in order for it to start pulling content for you. I'm assuming that's what is going on here; see for more details:

https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic/wiki/05.-SEO-Entry-Meta

Comment: Thanks khalwat, I'm a big fan of your plugin. I did resave the entries though, as I had to when writing new ones. Unless I'm missing some other thing.

Comment: @FuzzyJelly Did you make sure you dont have any old code related to setting Site Metas? If so you should get rid of that. I had the same issue a while back regarding the title that couldn't be set. This was due I had the basic Craft ones still there.

Comment: Yes, there aren't any additional titles or descriptions anywhere in any template.